# Android/Kotlin: Chaining method calls with condition

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an amount of - lets say 4 - methods. And I only want to execute the next one if the previous has an expected result (e.g. Boolean). Something like this:

```
if (isUserLoggedIn()) {
   if (userHasDoneTour()) {
     if(otherConditionalMethod()) {
        finalMethod()
     }
   }
}
```

Is there a better way to chain these conditional method calls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you don't do anything else in the outer if blocks it's better to combine them to a single if statement like

```
if (isUserLoggedIn() && userHasDoneTour() && otherConditionalMethod()) {
    finalMethod()
}
```

Comment: For the OP: this is called "short-circuiting". Using `&&` and `||` already has the behavior of skipping the later expression evaluations if the Boolean result has already been determined. If you don't want short-circuiting to take place, the `and` and `or` infix functions can be used instead.

Comment: Many thx, folks!